# Equivalent operators and expression for &=, ~, |= in VB.NET

Tags: c#, vb.net, operators

I need to convert the following lines of code in VB.NET but confused with the operators, can someone describe the name of these operators and their equivalent in VB:

```
long style= GetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_STYLE);
style &= ~(WS_VISIBLE);    // this works - window become invisible 

style |= WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW;   // flags don't work - windows remains in taskbar
style &= ~(WS_EX_APPWINDOW);
```

Comment: Bitwise operators. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz3k228a.aspx

Comment: Most operators of the `a op= b` pattern are just short hand for `a = a op b`

Comment: There are [**some**](http://converter.telerik.com/) [**nice**](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/?batchId=55d1612a-921c-4272-ab83-d6673bec3881) [**converters**](http://codeconverter.sharpdevelop.net/SnippetConverter.aspx) that can do it automatically.

Comment: Can someone just convert the last 3 lines in VB. I checked the converters but it converted using logical operators.

Comment: Pasting your example into the converter in the link, I get results using `Or`, `And` and `Not` which are the bitwise operators (or logical in the context of boolean values) not the short-cutting `OrElse` and `AndAlso` that are logical only.

Answer (score 1):

Since VB uses keywords for bitwise operators, it doesn't offer a shorthand self-assignment operator. You have to use:
X = X And Y and
X = X Or Y

Also, the equivalent to '~' is 'Not' (same keyword as logical 'Not', but different behaviour).